# Lotka-Volterra difference equation array-trouble

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, differential-equations

I am trying to write a program that graphically plots the Lotka-Volterra interaction between two species (fox and rabbit) using two difference equations.

The two equations in question are:

[image]

The initial state for rabit is supposed to be `R[0] = 100` and for fox `F[0] = 20`

Usually, when I'm encountered with numerically solving difference equations in python, I write something like this:

```
import numpy as np

N = 15
x = np.zeros(N+1, int)

x[0] = 1
x[1] = 1

for n in range(2, N+1):
    x[n] = x[n-1] + x[n-2]
    print(f"x[{n}] = {x[n]}")
```

I thought something like the strategy above also could work for the 'Lotka-Volterra-difference-equation' problem as well.

So I tried the following code and got a few unpleasant surprises:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 500
a = 0.4
b = 0.1
c = 0.005
e = 0.2

R = np.zeros(N+1)
F = np.zeros(N+1)
t = np.linspace(0,500,num=10_000)

R[0] = 100
F[0] = 20

for n in range(2,N):
    # Rabbit
    R[n] = R[n-1] + a*R[n-1] - c*R[n-1] * F[n-1]
    #Fox
    F[n] = F[n - 1] + e * c * R[n - 1] * F[n - 1] - b * F[n - 1]
    print(R[n],F[n])

plt.plot(t,R[n])
plt.show()
```

**The problems with the code is:**

**1. I don't produce any other out print than**

```
0.0 0.0
0.0 0.0
0.0 0.0
0.0 0.0
0.0 0.0
```

**2. It gives a lot of error messages if you try to plot it using matplotlib/pyplot.**

```
File "C:/Users/(...)lotka_volterra.py", line 36, in <module>
    plt.plot(t,R[n])
  File "C:\Users\(...)\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 3019, in plot
    return gca().plot(
  File "C:\Users\(...)\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 1605, in plot
    lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]
  File "C:\Users\(...)\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 315, in __call__
    yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\(...)\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 501, in _plot_args
    raise ValueError(f"x and y must have same first dimension, but "
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (10000,) and (1,)
```

Is there anyone who is kind enough to help me out with this problem? And perhaps also provide a solution?

All help is appreciated and welcomed.

Comment: @Andy: The correct initial state for fox is F[0] = 20 and for rabbit R[0] = 100. I'll edit that to make the question clearer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @Andy in his comment on your post, you set only the 0th index of both `R` and `F`, but your loop starts at index 2 and only looks back 1, meaning it never uses the 0th index of either array. Therefore, all subsequent equations will use only zeroes and thus every element of `R` and `F` are only being set to 0's, as you see in (1). To fix this, start your for loop at 1 and go to N:

```
for n in range(1,N):
    # etc
```

The plotting error is coming from the fact that your X-coordinates are from an array of 10,000 points while your y-coordinates are being chosen as only 1 from 500. You want both to be size 500, so you should define `t` as follows:

```
t = np.arange(0,N)
plt.plot(t, R)
```

Let me know if you have any other questions.

David

Comment: Thank you for a very clear and well-explained answer! You were and Andy was absolutely correct about the range issue. Now that the range now is set to range(1,N) it works pretty well for smaller iterations :-) However, now it has started to produce round-off overflow errors, so I better check my math. Also: I'm not very familiar with the np. arrange function. Should I use this instead of np.linspace or alongside the linspace function?

Comment: ```raceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/(...), line 37, in <module>
    plt.plot(t,R)
  File "C:\Users\(....), line 3019, in plot
    return gca().plot(
    lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]
  File "C:\Users\(...)\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 315, in __call__
    yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)
  File "...", line 501, in _plot_args
    raise ValueError(f"x and y must have same first dimension, but "
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (500,) and (51,)
```

Comment: @David: I also got this error trying to plot using ```np.arange(0,500)```

Comment: @fredericoamigo Notice that I am using `arange`, with one r. I also changed 500 to N to make it more general where N is the number of iterations you'd want.

Comment: Haha, ops! I'm sorry, my English spelling can be sub-optimal sometimes. Norwegian is my native laguage.

Comment: I still cant get the plot to work even though i swapped np.linspace() with ```t = np.arange(0,N)```. My ploting statements are ````plt.plot(t,R)``` and ```plt.show()``` Any chance of spotting whats wrong?

Comment: Hmm.. it seems to work better when i change ```R = np.zeros(N+1)```` and ````F = np.zeros(N+1)``` to ```R = np.zeros(N)```` and ````F = np.zeros(N)```